# spring boot / thymeleaf nested loop object access

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf to create a single landing page for
my application. For this, I need to render a List of Host objects that all
contain a Container.
Here is the relevant code:

```
public class Container {
    private String name;
    private String baseUrl;
    private String status;

    public Container(String name, String baseUrl, String status) {
        this.name = name;
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getBaseUrl() { return baseUrl; }
    public String getStatus() { return status; }
}

public class Host {
    private HashMap<String, Container> containers;
    ....
    public List<Container> getContainers() {
         return containers.values();
    }
}

@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {
      @RequestMapping("/")
      public String getIndex(Model model) {
          model.addAttribute("hosts", hostRepository.getAllServers());
          return "index";
      }
}
```

Now I want to iterate over all servers and display the information about each Container in a table.
My Thymeleaf template looks like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" th:each="host : ${hosts}">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <b th:text="${host.name}">Host X</b>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>URL</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr th:each="container : ${host.getContainers()}">
           <!-- HERE IS THE PROBLEM -->
                                <td th:text="${container.name}">Service1</td>
                                <td th:text="${container.baseUrl}">domain.com/api/url</td>
                                <td th:text="${container.status}">RUNNING</td>
           <!-- HERE ENDS THE PROBLEM -->
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

My problem is the part where is access the container's properties (marked by the commentary).
Every time I get a SpringEL Exception. If I remove the `th:text="${container.xy}"` and replaces it with `th:text="${container}` a String version of the container is shown so I have access to the object and the loop it working properly. I also tried to replace the field access with getters (e.g. `getStatus()`) but it also does not work.

Thanks for your help. If you need more information, feel free to ask.

Setup:

- Java 8
- Spring Boot Starter Web
- Thymeleaf

**edit**: The exception thrown is: `nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "container.name" (index:35)` where index:35 is the first problematic line.

The toString() output when using `${container}` is `jenkins=com.my.app.Container@7552c269` and jenkins is the `name` attribute of the Container instance.

**Solution** It seemed that the nested loop was iterating over a Map instead of a List. Changing `${container.xy}` to `${container.getValue().xy}` solved the problem.

Comment: **What** exception? This most likely means that you have a typo in your SpEL expression, if you're getting a correct `toString` output when you drop the `.xy`.

Comment: ${host.getContainer()} should be ${host.getContainers()}

Comment: @TommySchmidt Made a typo in the class, fixed that.

Comment: @chrylis: `nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "container.name" (index:35)` is the exception where index:35 is the line where I use `container.name`.

Comment: Thanks. Please edit that into your question.

Comment: Also, there should be *another* nested exception. And sorry to ask the obvious, but can you post all your getters for `Container`? (I usually use Groovy or Lombok to avoid any potential issues like this.)

Comment: can you also post the string version if you use ${container}

Comment: Edited my post and included the string version and the getters.

Comment: can you override the toString method to display the following: Container[name='the name property'] and post the output for toString again?

Comment: The output is `postgres=Container[name=postgres]` although toString() should only return the part after the `=`. I've dug into the stack trace and `EL1008E:(pos 10): Property or field 'name' cannot be found on object of type 'org.thymeleaf.util.EvaluationUtil$MapEntry' - maybe not public?` was reported. I have no clue that this object is but maybe it helps.

Comment: it seems that spring is taking the map as result of ${container} and not the list (specified by getContainers). can you try ${container.getValue().name} in your td tags pls

Comment: Wow, this really solved it! Thank you very much :)

Comment: you should post the solution as an answer

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

It seemes that the nested loop was iterating over a `org.thymeleaf.util.EvaluationUtil$MapEntry` instead of a List. Changing `${container.xy}` to `${container.getValue().xy}` solved the problem.

Bits learned along the way:

- Override the `toString()` method to obtain formatted information about the object iterating over. In this case the output was `key=value` which altough `value` was expected. This gave a hint that the current object must be something else than a `Container` instance
- Look at the stack trace of Thymeleaf (usually its a hint that something is null or not public)
- Use `getClass()` on the current object during the iteration to check if something went wrong here